# How to match a formatted date to an Array within Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

**Problem**

I'm unable to have a formatted date match an array of dates in Google Apps Script. More specifically for me, I am having my script pull todays date, and see if it's in an array of data (to match). See below for log results as it seems like I do have a match.

I am also unsure how to pull in data if there is a match to the array item from a corresponding column. I'm assuming I'd use some form of `for` statement that I have in my code, but unsure how to get it working properly.

For the example below, for simplicity, let's say todays date is 12/06/2022.

**Solution Sought**

1. Check to see if todays date is in the array
2. if yes, pull in the code color (from column A) into column C next to the matched date.

**Expected Results**

[image]

**Actual Results**

[image]

**What I've Tried**

1. Attempted to find an answer similar to mine on stackoverflow but was unable to find a related enough question
2. Tried to use indexOf with <-1 to see if my transformDate would process that way with my array, but to no avail sadly
3. Uncertain how to use .map() and if that would help with my scenario

**CODE**

```js
function tDate(){

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let date = new Date();//creates dates
  var transformDate = Utilities.formatDate(date,"EST","MM/dd/yyyy");//reformats into month/2 digit day/4 digit year 

  var codeDateArray = ssName.getRange(2,2,ssName.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat(); //getting the values using DisplayValues and then making the 2-d array into 1, as I think that's supposed to help with my function

  for (let a=0;a<codeDateArray.length;a++){
      if (transformDate in codeDateArray){
        var codeVal = ssName.getRange(a+2,2).getValue();
        ssName.getRange(a+2,3).setValue(codeVal)

      }//end of IF statement
      else {ssName.getRange(2,4).setValue(-1);}//end of ELSE statement...here to showcase if my IF fails for testing
  }//end of FOR statement, derived from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423183/google-app-script-formatted-date-match-in-array-without-iterating) @Tanaike & (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207471/find-and-match-a-date-in-array) @christophebazin


}//end of function
```

**LOG RESULTS**

The first dates are the "code date" and the second date is todays date (transformDate).

[image]

**EXAMPLE DATA**

| code color | code date | code pull in | negative test results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | 12/06/2022 |  |  |
| red | 12/10/2022 |  |  |
| orange | 12/11/2025 |  |  |

**Relatable questions on StackOverflow**

1. [unable to get index of date in array with apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70918960/unable-to-get-index-of-date-in-array-with-apps-script)
2. [Find and match a date in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207471/find-and-match-a-date-in-array)
3. [Google App Script formatted date Match in Array without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423183/google-app-script-formatted-date-match-in-array-without-iterating)

Comment: On first look, your `if` is wrong.  It should be something like `if (transformDate === codeDateArray[a]){`. Also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612/what-does-the-range-method-getvalues-return-and-setvalues-accept

Comment: so this is very interesting, thank you for the direction to the question...I changed this part: 

`if (transformDate in codeDateArray){`

to  `if (transformDate === codeDateArray[a]){`
     
however, now the function is providing both my solution and the `else` statement. is that correct? Seems like it shouldn't be performing the `else` statement

Comment: Use valueOf() or getTime()

Comment: @Cooper instead of `new Date()`?

Comment: valueOf() and getTime() are methods of Date() object that are used to compare date values numerically.

Comment: ok thank you, I wasn't sure! Tried to look it up in the Google developers section and didn't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of putting `if (transformDate in codeDateArray)` inside a `for` loop sounds broken.

The whole thing may be easiest to do by collecting results with `map()`, like this:

```js
function tDate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const codeDateRange = sheet.getRange('B2:B');
  const colors = codeDateRange.offset(0, -1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const codeDateArray = codeDateRange.getDisplayValues().flat();
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const todayString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  const result = codeDateArray
    .map((dateString, index) => [dateString === todayString ? colors[index] : null]);
  codeDateRange.offset(0, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: thank you @doubleunary this was very helpful, and I was just looking into `.map()` as i'm still beginning to learn how to use it. for `colors[index]` I had to use `colors[0]`, does that seem right? I was getting an error that said index was not defined. 

Also what does the `?` do in the map function, is that like `&&` to chain further conditions? 

Thanks!!

Comment: Edited the answer to replace `dateString` with `(dateString, index)`. See [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 2):

The `if` logic is wrong. Use

```
if (transformDate === codeDateArray[a]){
```

instead. You would also need to `break` out of the loop,  once the  condition is satisfied and move the `else` block outside the loop, else the `else` block will execute on every loop.

```
for (let a = 0; a < codeDateArray.length; a++) {
  if (transformDate === codeDateArray[a]) {
    var codeVal = ssName.getRange(a + 2, 2).getValue();
    ssName.getRange(a + 2, 3).setValue(codeVal);
    break;
  } //end of IF statement
} //end of FOR statement
if (a === codeDateArray.length /*Counter is at the end*/) {
  ssName.getRange(2, 4).setValue(-1);
} //end of ELSE statement...here to showcase if my IF fails for testing
```

#### To read:

[Control Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling)

Comment: thank you @TheMaster as always super helpful! Appreciate the links to the documentation on 2-d arrays w/the `getDisplayValues()` as I didn't know that was a thing.  Also good to know about the `else` statement execution.